# Change JSLint NetBeans plugin properties to tolerate whitespaces and missing 'use strict' statements ?

Tags: netbeans, jslint

I've installed JSLint plugin for NetBeans and everything is fine, but somehow I want it to tolerate whitespaces and  missing 'use strict' statements. Is there any chance to do that? I'm talking for NetBeans 7.3 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find information on project-based jslint settings for this plugin.

However, jslint's [comment-style options](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#options) should work if you place it at the top of the files that require these settings:

```
/*jslint white: true, sloppy: true */
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to this question, in Netbeans 7.4 you can go through Tools/Options/Miscellaneous and select the JSLint tab, there you can set the following options

- Tolerate missing 'use strict' pragma
- Tolerate messy white space